# Force mapstruct not to call has* methods

Tags: java, mapping, mapstruct

I wrote a mapstruct mapper that uses a mapping like this:

```
@Mapping(target = "userId", source = "id.userId")
```

When I looked at the autogenerated mapstruct class I stubled upon that code:

```
if ( !foobar.hasId() ) {
    return null;
}
```

This is a problem for me as `hasId()` does not what mapstruct expects here. Can I force mapstruct somehow to not generate code that uses this method but checks for `id != null` or something?

I could use a mapping like `@Mapping(target = "userId", expression= "java(...)")` but I think there should be another way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can force MapStruct not to use those `presenceCheckers`. You can find more information in [source presence checking](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#source-presence-check) in the documentation.

Basically the only way to do this is to provide an implementation of the MapStruct [`AccessorNamingStrategy`](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/ap/spi/AccessorNamingStrategy.html). You can just extend the [`DefaultAccessorNamingStrategy`](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/ap/spi/DefaultAccessorNamingStrategy.html) and override its`isPresenceCheckMethod`.

You have access to the method `ExecutableElement` and you can check the type of class it is in and other things as well.

```
MyAccessorNamingStrategy extends DefaultAccessorNamingStrategy {

    @Override
    public boolean isPresenceCheckMethod(ExecutableElement element) {
        //You can do your checks here. You can ignore certain methods, from certain classes

    }
```

Remember to register your SPI with a file `META-INF-/services/com.example.MyAccessorNamingStrategy`

There is also the [examples](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples) where you can find an example for the SPI.

Answer (score 2):

MapStruct is treating the `hasId()` method as a [source presence checker](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#source-presence-check) method, only setting the `id` value if it returns `true`.

If `conditionExpression` is specified, it is used instead of the source presence checker method.  By specifying an always-true value for this, the value will always be mapped, rather than conditionally based on the result of `hasId()`.

```java
@Mapping(target = "userId", source = "id.userId", conditionExpression = "java(true)")
```

This results in the generated code like the following:

```java
if ( true ) {
    target.setUserId( userId );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42306521/1108305) that suggests providing your own `AccessorNamingStrategy` explains how to solve this in general, often disabling the source presence checker is overkill.  I think your solution of using `expression` is probably often the right answer in terms of simplicity for a one-off override.

```java
@Mapping(target = "userId", expression="java(source.getId().getUserId())")
MyTargetType map(MySourceType source);
```

or

```java
@Mapping(target = "userId", source="id")
MyTargetType map(MySourceType source);

default String map(MySourceTypeId id) {
  return id == null ? null : id.getUserId();
}
```